# Solr record are not showing

Tags: mysql, solr

I am new to solr so sorry it this is a basic question.

I am following this example:

http://entropytc.com/importing-a-mysql-database-into-apache-solr/#codesyntax_3

I have add record on my server and it is showing this result:

```
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
<int name="status">0</int>
<int name="QTime">0</int>
</lst>
<lst name="initArgs">
<lst name="defaults">
<str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
</lst>
</lst>
<str name="command">full-import</str>
<str name="status">idle</str>
<str name="importResponse"/>
<lst name="statusMessages">
<str name="Total Requests made to DataSource">1</str>
<str name="Total Rows Fetched">62</str>
<str name="Total Documents Skipped">0</str>
<str name="Full Dump Started">2014-07-23 04:12:02</str>
<str name="">
Indexing completed. Added/Updated: 0 documents. Deleted 0 documents.
</str>
<str name="Committed">2014-07-23 04:12:02</str>
<str name="Total Documents Processed">0</str>
<str name="Time taken">0:0:0.824</str>
</lst>
<str name="WARNING">
This response format is experimental. It is likely to change in the future.
</str>
</response>
```

but when i search my records it give me nothing:

```
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
<int name="status">0</int>
<int name="QTime">0</int>
<lst name="params">
<str name="start">0</str>
<str name="q">*:*</str>
<str name="rows">10</str>
<str name="indent">on</str>
<str name="version">2.2</str>
</lst>
</lst>
<result name="response" numFound="0" start="0"/>
</response>
```

what am i doing wrong

Comment: What does your data-config.xml look like? You're not importing any documents: `Indexing completed. Added/Updated: 0 documents. Deleted 0 documents.`

Comment: You should also run it through the interactive debug mode: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Interactive_Development_Mode